# How to use POST in HTML to do the action below?

Tags: html, post, web, blogspot

I have a blog where I have embedded the Captcha of Solve Media.

I want to enter a button where it sends POST to a web address. All that is stated below. Also the text will be entered in the text box just below the captcha. 
Please tell me what will be the HTML code for sending the particular post to that address.
Also tell me how can my website detect the IP of user (as I have to send it by POST to Solve Media)
Thank You

This is what is stated at the Solve Media website.This is also given at portal.solvemedia.com/portal/help/pub/implement--->

Verifying

To verify the user's answer,
Send a http POST to http://verify.solvemedia.com/papi/verify with the following parameters:
privatekey
Your verification key (V-Key)
challenge
The puzzle challenge identifier - typically found in the form field adcopy_challenge
response
The user's answer from the form field adcopy_response
remoteip
The user's IP address
You will receive a response consisting of three lines
Line 1
True or false. True if the user passed, false otherwise.
Line 2
Error message. If line 1 is false, a brief explanatory message explaining the reason
Line 3
Message authenticator. You may use this to verify that the response came from us, and was not tampered with in any way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to use post:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- Your HTML elements to be send via post -->
</form>
```

You must Specify the location in action that the form navigates to when it submit.

I think you want to send all the details to http://verify.solvemedia.com/papi/verify, so your code will look something like:

```
<form action="http://verify.solvemedia.com/papi/verify" method="post">
    <!-- Your HTML elements to be send via post-->
</form>
```

Hope this will help.